# TIBCO BW custom javafunction via library jar

Tags: java, xpath, jar, businessworks, tibco-business-works

I used a java class to create a custom BW XPATH function ,its working as expected.

But now i want to create a JAR file with all the custom functions, we want for our company and place them in TIBCO LIB.
I request a procedure from any on how to do this without using any individual class files .By this way i can add a bunch of java files which are available readily for other developers from the functions menu

I tried defining an alias, as of now only option is by :

1. writing a single class which uses all the functions and keep all the dependency classes in a jar
2. Place the jar in LIB
3. Define a custom Java function and load the class

By this ear, no need to contain all the classes, only the main class is packaged with ear.

What I am trying exactly is similar to BW functions we have in the designer xpath functions options.

placing a JAR and updating a config some where should solve this. Requesting the big community help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You could create all the classes required and wrap the compiled classes under jar file. Place this jar file under classpath.
Here are couple of pointers:

1. Make sure java version used to compile the classes and the version used in *designer.tra/bwengine.tra*
2. Class need not have a main method
3. Class must implement *Serializable* in order to be able to use
4. Place the jar file under *BW_HOME/version no/hotfix/lib* directory
5. In case, designer is started already, please restart after placing the jar file.

   Assuming that you know how call methods of your class. I would just add here some more info in case if it might be of help

BW can call java methods like you can do in java i.e., one can instantiate Java class and call its methods instead of calling a main method that you mention. Here is how you do which can be done in two ways:

1. Create a global object for the class like you do shareconnection like jms, jdbc and use this across the processes
2. In case you need it in each job, then it would be good to have a java method activity to instantiate java class(choose constructor here) and pass this output to input of another java method activity where it takes instantiated class object and method parameters.
   Hope this helps.